# Performance of spark.effects.Effect classes

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, effects, flex4.6

I'm trying to determine the performance of the Spark Effect classes. I'm not sure how to determine this.

There are a couple of properties that look like they might increase performance. The disableLayout property, suspendBackgroundProcessing and applyChangesPostLayout.

Somewhere I read that suspendBackgroundProcessing is this is not enabled because it's needed for validation, I think in the override of said property.

I setup tests at one point where I set an effect on repeat and looked at the FPS. Changing the previous properties made a difference in frame rate from 3 to 12fps but I'm not sure how they affected the behavior ( I slightly do but in some cases the results were the same regardless of those options ). I also putting effects in a sequence and tested setting targets in the sequence effect vs setting target or targets on the effects themselves. The Sequence composite effect has a target property that passes this value to the child effects if set. Internally different code is run.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the performance to be poor and now try to avoid it.

Our card flipping uses spark.effects and it works find on desktop & web, however when we cross complied to iOS it failed badly, we changed it to pure flash animation and it runs perfectly.

In general I believe the spark components to be flawed for anything that requires high performance.